# Python/gtk gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file() always fails

Tags: python, pygtk

Hi I'm trying to use a python gtk script under python 2.7.3; on Linux (under X11) and it needs to load images into pixbufs from disk.

However, python returns a glib.GError: "Couldn't recognize the image file format" regardless of what type of file I try to open; 
eg: with: pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file( filename )

I can do a gtk.gdk.pixbuf_get_formats(), and in the list of dictionaries which is returned, the formats I have tried to load are listed .png, .ppm, .jpg.

When I try a gtk.gdk.pixbuf_get_file_info( filename ), though, it returns None.

Other GTK based programs such as Gimp, load these same images just fine; and gtk scripts that don't load icons from disk, but which draw buttons -- etc. work just fine.

How would I search for the cause of this malfunction?

Am I missing some kind of a mime-type file ?

Is there an alternate path using other gtk function calls that might accomplish the loading another way?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gtk

def win_with_image():
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("photo.png")
    print pixbuf
    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    image = gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
    win.add(image)
    win.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win_with_image()
    gtk.main()
```

If this doesn`t work for you, try to:

- start google and type your error and choose the second link (http://aptosid.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=2246), in general this helps almost always.
- reinstall libglib
- install gtk (maybe some graphical libs - libpng, libjpeg, f.e.)
- reinstall python/gtk package
- fix broken package repository
- change files permissions